# TinkerPop: Filter by edge count with specific property

Tags: python-2.7, gremlin

With the following diagram:

[DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALQyv.png)

I want to get the users who has at least two post in the location 2.

I tried to count the edges filtering by his properties but nothing happens:

`g.V().hasLabel("user").outE('POST').outV().filter(outE('LOCATED_AT').limit(2).has('country_code', 'CZ').count().is_(2)).count().toList()`

The query actually returns a timeout. I spent many hours finding a way to do that but no ones can replicate this query.

Answer (score 0):

Get the users who has at least two post in the location 2:

```
from gremlin_python.structure.graph import Graph
from gremlin_python.process.traversal import T, Column, P
from gremlin_python.process.graph_traversal import __

g.V().hasLabel("user").filter(__.outE('POST').inV().out('LOCATED_AT').has('country_code', 'CZ').groupCount().unfold().select(Column.values).is_(P.gte(2))).toList()
```

In your diagram, could not find out where to put the property `country_code`, so the code to generate graph:

```
g.addV('user').property('Id', 1).property(T.id, '11').iterate()
g.addV('user').property('Id', 2).property(T.id, '12').iterate()

g.addV('media').property('Id', 1).property(T.id, '21').iterate()
g.addV('media').property('Id', 2).property(T.id, '22').iterate()
g.addV('media').property('Id', 3).property(T.id, '23').iterate()
g.addV('media').property('Id', 4).property(T.id, '24').iterate()

g.addV('location').property('Id', 1).property(T.id, '31').property('country_code', 'CZ').iterate()
g.addV('location').property('Id', 2).property(T.id, '32').property('country_code', 'CZ').iterate()
g.addV('location').property('Id', 3).property(T.id, '33').property('country_code', 'CZ').iterate()

g.addE('POST').from_(g.V('11')).to(g.V('21')).iterate()
g.addE('POST').from_(g.V('11')).to(g.V('22')).iterate()
g.addE('POST').from_(g.V('11')).to(g.V('23')).iterate()
g.addE('POST').from_(g.V('12')).to(g.V('24')).iterate()

g.addE('LOCATED_AT').from_(g.V('21')).to(g.V('31')).iterate()
g.addE('LOCATED_AT').from_(g.V('22')).to(g.V('32')).iterate()
g.addE('LOCATED_AT').from_(g.V('23')).to(g.V('32')).iterate()
g.addE('LOCATED_AT').from_(g.V('24')).to(g.V('32')).iterate()
g.addE('LOCATED_AT').from_(g.V('24')).to(g.V('33')).iterate()
```